# Cannot import ssm string list variable in serverless v3

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-ssm

I am in the process of upgrading my serverless project from version 1.7 to 3, but I am facing an issue when deploying with the SSM variable. I have an SSM variable which is a string list, but if I try to import it in the usual way it throws an error saying. When I checked the documentation it says it will automatically process the string list. But in my case, it is throwing an error. How can I fix this and successfully work with a string list?

```
Environment/Variables/VARIABLE_NAME: expected type: String, found: JSONArray
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Serverless Framework [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables) there is section called **Resolve StringList as array of strings**. It mentions that you can do the following:

```
${ssm(raw):/path/to/stringlistparam}
```

This seemed to have resolved my error and returned the values I was expecting from the parameter.

Hope this helps!